# Don't find an activity on AndroidManifest

Tags: android

Good afternoon,

I have an activity that calls another. The code is as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Menu.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

When I run the application get the following error:

**android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {proyecto.uvigo/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

I do not understand what is wrong because I have already stated, the Activity Menu on the AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="proyecto.uvigo"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Inicio"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<activity android:name=".Login"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Menu"></activity>
<activity android:name=".RecuperarPass"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Auxiliar"></activity>
<activity android:name=".MiPerfil"></activity>
<activity android:name=".CambiarPass"></activity>
</application>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but there is something wrong with `Unable to find explicit activity class {proyecto.uvigo/android.view.Menu};`. Why `android.view.Menu`?. Please, check if import android.view.Menu class. If yes, use this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), proyecto.uvigo.Menu.class);
```

or import `proyecto.uvigo.Menu` instead of `android.view.Menu`.

Answer (score 5):

It's because your code is using `android.view.Menu` as an `Activity` instead of your `Menu` class. Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), proyecto.uvigo.Menu.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Alternately, you could rename your `Menu` class to something like `UvigoMenu` or `UvigoMenuActivity` in your class and in your manifest, just to avoid confusion like this.

Answer (score 1):

start Menu activity as:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), proyecto.uvigo.Menu.class);
startActivity(i);
```

or

```
Intent i= new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("proyecto.uvigo", "proyecto.uvigo.Menu"));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<activity android:name=".Menu"></activity>
```

to

```
<activity android:name=".Menu">
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```